# How to use browser back button with routing for going back to component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, routes

I can successfully go from the `Home` component to `TacoTypes` component with routing.  But what I'm struggling with is going from `TacoTypes` component to `Home` component with routing using the browser back button.

`/ChooseTruck` is the path name I gave in an attempt to navigate back to it from `TacoTypes` component.

I've read up on the documentation and tried following it but it just won't work.  How can I make this happen?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../../components/Home/Home';

import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';

class TacoTypes extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Aux>
                <Link to={{pathname: '/ChooseTruck'}} />
                <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            </Aux>
        );
    }
}

export default TacoTypes;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use `Fragment` component instead of making `Aux`. Concept is easy and it's actually does the same as `Aux`, but it's built in and you can use it rightaway. Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Now let's get to your question. Why your path is `/ChooseTruck`? I don't really understand this. When you want to navigate back to home using `Link` component just make path `/` as It is below in the `Route` component. Additionally when you want to use just back browser button use it.

`react-router-dom` is making stack of the paths, so when you navigate to the `TacoTypes` component and want back to previous URL just hit back browser button, or use `withRouter` hoc and there you got `goBack()` method which is also navigating to the previous URL.

Comment: Yeah that's the issue.  When I hit back button, I see `/ChooseTruck` path but not the actual contents of the component.  Nonetheless,  I changed both of the paths to `/` in `Link` and `Route` but still no luck.

Comment: Okay. I think I know why is that. You have the `Route` component inside `TacoTypes` component which is not called since the path for `TacoTypes` is different. Please move the `<Route path="/" exact component={Home} />` higher, so it's not conflicted with other routes and see what's happening.

Comment: I actually tried that before but it didn't work and now tried it again, still doesn't work :(

Comment: This seems strange. Have you checked you have the same path in `Link` and `Route`? Also still have the `Route` outside the `TacoTypes` component. Probably the best will be having all `Routes` inside highest component in DOM possible.

Comment: Yeah Link and Route have the same path in my TacoTypes component.  When you say outside of TacoTypes component, I don't think that's possible.  It needs to be inside return()

Comment: I mean inside return, but in the component which is higher. I guess you got `App` component. Put it there and try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179836/discussion-between-sp92-and-szymon-pancerz).